# Jade cannot read property length

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have my post.js as

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var db = require('monk')('localhost/nodeblog');

router.get('/add', function(req, res, next) {
    var categories = db.get('categories');

    categories.find({},{},function (err, categories){
        res.render('addpost', {
            "title": "Add Post",
            'categories': categories
        });
    });
});

router.post('/add', function(req, res, next){
   //get form values
    var title       = req.body.title;
    var category    = req.body.category;
    var body        = req.body.body;
    var author      = req.body.author;
    var date        = new Date();

    console.log(req.body);
    if(req.file){
        var mainImageOriginalName   = req.file.originalname;
        var mainImageName           = req.file.filename;
        var mainImageSize           = req.file.size;
        var mainImageMime           = req.file.mimetype;
        var mainImageExt            = req.file.extension;
        var mainImagePath           = req.file.path;
    } else {
        var mainImageName   = 'noimage.png';
    }

    //form validation
    req.checkBody('title', 'Title field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('body', 'Body field is required').notEmpty();

    //check errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('addpost', {
            'errors'    : errors,
            'title'     : title,
            'body'      : body
            'categories': category
        });
    } else {
        var posts = db.get('posts');

        //submit to db
        posts.insert({
            'title': title,
            'body': body,
            'category': category,
            'date': date,
            'author': author,
            'image': mainImageName
        }, function (err, post){
            if(err){
                res.send('There was an issue submitting the post');
            } else {
                req.flash('success', 'Post submitted');
                res.location('/');
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

and my addpost.jade as

```
extends layout

block content
    h1=title
    ul.errors
        if errors
            each error, i in errors
                li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}

    form(method='post', action='/posts/add', enctype='multipart/form-data')
        .form-group
            label Title
            input.form-control(name='title', type='text')
        .form-group
            label Category
            select.form-control(name='category')
                each category, i in categories
                    option(value='#{category.title}') #{category.title}
        .form-group
            label Body
            textarea.form-control(name='body', id='body')
        .form-group
            label Main Image
            input.form-control(name='image', type='file')
        .form-group
            label Author
            select.form-control(name='author')
                option(value='Shehzad Shaikh') Shehzad Shaikh
                option(value='John Doe') John Doe
        input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit', value='Save')

        script(src='/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')
        script
            | CKEDITOR.replace('body');
```

When i submit the form, it gives me an error which says

`nodeblog/views/addpost.jade:20 18| label Category 19| select.form-control(name='category') > 20| each category, i in categories 21| option(value='#{category.title}') #{category.title} 22| .form-group 23| label Body Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

I checked the variable names, looks fine to me. What actually went wrong?
Also If something's wrong with the select box, it is rendering the values correctly, however this issue is popping up when submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(errors){
    res.render('addpost', {
        'errors'    : errors,
        'title'     : title,
        'body'      : body
    });
}
```

From what I understand, if there is an error during your post, you render the same view providing the errors. Still, you didn't provide `categories` so it's undefined when Jade(Pug) renders the view. I guess that's where the error comes from... ?

Comment: Thanx for the advice, but that didnt help.

Comment: Are you sure?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdKyEv // No categories -> error
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWRMXN // categories array -> rendered

Comment: Yes, it is getting rendered but the same error pops up while submitting.

Comment: Guys, still I am having the same issue? Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Adding an if condition in the jade file solved mine.

```
    .form-group
        label Category
        select.form-control(name='category')
            if categories
                each category,i in categories
                    option(value='#{category.title}') #{category.title}
```